# Join all one to many results as new fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, gis

I want to join all possible results (up to 5 counties intersect ZIP codes) from ZIP_County_Intersect to be populated as the null County fields in ZIP_County_Dissolve. These results are coming from GIS (ArcGIS Pro) but I don't know a quick way in GIS to get more than the first result from a one-to-many join added to the dissolve table, so I am hoping I can do this using SQL Server (SSMS).

Using the screenshots below as an example, I want the ZIP_County_Dissolve table to be updated so County1 = Sumter, County1_SqMiles = 4.46296251, County2 = Clarendon, County2_SqMiles = 62.52092399. Even better would be having the results ordered by largest SqMiles_ZIPparts so County1 = Clarendon, County1_SqMiles = 62.52092399, County2 = Sumter, County2_SqMiles = 4.46296251. How to do in SQL Server?

ZIP_County_Dissolve:
[image: ZIP_County_Dissolve]

ZIP_County_Intersect:
[image: ZIP_County_Intersect]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: if you pivot zip_county_interesct on zipcode, you should be able to do it quite easily. If you attach some test data in form of text table, someone might even do the work for you :)

Comment: @siggemannen I think you meant unpivot

Comment: hmm, not sure, i was thinking something like: select row_number() over(partition by zipcode order by sqlmiles_zipparts) from ZIP_County_Intersect and then pivot the values based on the ROW_NUMBER rank between 1 and 5 and join it against ZIP_County_Dissolve